# What's the standard way to run a Clojure product in production?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

What's the standard way to run a Clojure product in production? is it to lein run or make a java jar and run it? Also, my main only calls an infinite go-loop. works fine when I run it from repl but lein run and java -jar uberjar file both seem to not keep an open process. Wondering if anyone can advise on this.

Comment: Can you generate a [mre] letting someone else see the problem (with `java -jar uberjar`) themselves?

Comment: ...as long as your main blocks on a return value from a channel the goroutines never write to (at least, unless a clean shutdown has been requested), it should genuinely hang around forever; but if you don't show us your main, we can't see if you're doing that (or any equivalent to it) or not.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you'd run it as an uber-jar, as you mentioned, with `java -jar my-uber.jar`

Comment: AFAICT, this isn't the OP's "real question", which is more about their `main` returning immediately when they want it to keep running until a goroutine (designed to continue running indefinitely) completes.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with you that only one "real" question was intended. Either way, this is a correct answer to one of the two questions actually asked.